# unable to render facebook login button on android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

i'm facing a strange problem with facebook login button of facebook android sdk 4. 
I've follow the guide to convert my previous code (i've used old facebook sdk), but android studio could not render correctly the button.
this is my login button code:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fb_button"
    style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-14dp"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    fb:login_text="@string/login_with_facebook"
    fb:logout_text="Logout" />
```

wbhere facebook login button style is

```
 <style name="FacebookLoginButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_facebook</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">21sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
```

now when i try to see preview on android studio, i've this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:410)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onCreate, onCreateView and onViewCreated in your fragment.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends");
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    setFacebookLoginText(loginButton);
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook_login, container, false);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: It's not a application problem (it works fine and button is showed). It's only a problem on android studio preview of layout

Comment: The same "problem" have all other users. Button isn't rendering in preview. But I don't think it is the "problem", cause it works fine. Maybe, in new version, Facebook will fix this.

Comment: My button stopped rendering in the app for no reason! No matter what I  do, I see the default button. I even copy pasted the original class and layout from an older version, restarted my phone, the notebook, cleaned, rebuilt the project. Nothing helped. Has anyone encountered that?